# unable to access S3 buckets using bucketeer with heroku

Tags: amazon-s3, heroku

I have a Django project that stores some media files in AWS S3.  As this is deployed on `heroku` I am using the [bucketeer](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bucketeer) addon for this.  But when I try to list the contents of my bucket (either in code using `boto3` or via the AWS CLI as below) I keep getting access denied errors.

**.aws/config**

```
[profile my-profile]
aws_access_key_id=whatever
aws_secret_access_key=whatever
region=us-east-1
```

`aws --profile my-profile s3 ls s3:///bucket-name`

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?